# linux does not recognize my midi controller samson

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-device-driver, midi

Sorry for my english

I have a problem a midi controller, a Samson Carbon 61. When I connect via usb, dmesg tells me the following.

```
[ 1480.097123] usb 2-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 9 using ehci_hcd
[ 1480.118082] usb 2-1.1: no configurations
[ 1480.118087] usb 2-1.1: can't read configurations, error -22
[ 1480.118206] hub 2-1:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 1
```

aplaymidi -l command tells me the following

```
Port Client name Port name
14:0 Midi Through Midi Through Port-0
```

sudo lsusb -v command tells me the following

```
 Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Device Descriptor:
bLength 18
bDescriptorType 1
bcdUSB 2.00
bDeviceClass 9 Hub
bDeviceSubClass 0 Unused
bDeviceProtocol 0 Full speed (or root) hub
bMaxPacketSize0 64
idVendor 0x1d6b Linux Foundation
idProduct 0x0002 2.0 root hub
bcdDevice 3.02
iManufacturer 3 Linux 3.2.0-58-generic ehci_hcd
iProduct 2 EHCI Host Controller
iSerial 1 0000:00:1a.0
bNumConfigurations 1
Configuration Descriptor:
bLength 9
bDescriptorType 2
wTotalLength 25
bNumInterfaces 1
bConfigurationValue 1
iConfiguration 0
bmAttributes 0xe0
Self Powered
Remote Wakeup
MaxPower 0mA
Interface Descriptor:
bLength 9
bDescriptorType 4
bInterfaceNumber 0
bAlternateSetting 0
bNumEndpoints 1
bInterfaceClass 9 Hub
bInterfaceSubClass 0 Unused
bInterfaceProtocol 0 Full speed (or root) hub
iInterface 0
Endpoint Descriptor:
bLength 7
bDescriptorType 5
bEndpointAddress 0x81 EP 1 IN
bmAttributes 3
Transfer Type Interrupt
Synch Type None
Usage Type Data
wMaxPacketSize 0x0004 1x 4 bytes
bInterval 12
Hub Descriptor:
bLength 9
bDescriptorType 41
nNbrPorts 2
wHubCharacteristic 0x000a
No power switching (usb 1.0)
Per-port overcurrent protection
bPwrOn2PwrGood 10 * 2 milli seconds
bHubContrCurrent 0 milli Ampere
DeviceRemovable 0x00
PortPwrCtrlMask 0xff
Hub Port Status:
Port 1: 0000.0507 highspeed power suspend enable connect
Port 2: 0000.0100 power
Device Status: 0x0001
Self Powered

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Device Descriptor:
bLength 18
bDescriptorType 1
bcdUSB 2.00
bDeviceClass 9 Hub
bDeviceSubClass 0 Unused
bDeviceProtocol 0 Full speed (or root) hub
bMaxPacketSize0 64
idVendor 0x1d6b Linux Foundation
idProduct 0x0002 2.0 root hub
bcdDevice 3.02
iManufacturer 3 Linux 3.2.0-58-generic ehci_hcd
iProduct 2 EHCI Host Controller
iSerial 1 0000:00:1d.0
bNumConfigurations 1
Configuration Descriptor:
bLength 9
bDescriptorType 2
wTotalLength 25
bNumInterfaces 1
bConfigurationValue 1
iConfiguration 0
bmAttributes 0xe0
Self Powered
Remote Wakeup
MaxPower 0mA
Interface Descriptor:
bLength 9
bDescriptorType 4
bInterfaceNumber 0
bAlternateSetting 0
bNumEndpoints 1
bInterfaceClass 9 Hub
bInterfaceSubClass 0 Unused
bInterfaceProtocol 0 Full speed (or root) hub
iInterface 0
Endpoint Descriptor:
bLength 7
bDescriptorType 5
bEndpointAddress 0x81 EP 1 IN
bmAttributes 3
Transfer Type Interrupt
Synch Type None
Usage Type Data
wMaxPacketSize 0x0004 1x 4 bytes
bInterval 12
Hub Descriptor:
bLength 9
bDescriptorType 41
nNbrPorts 2
wHubCharacteristic 0x000a
No power switching (usb 1.0)
Per-port overcurrent protection
bPwrOn2PwrGood 10 * 2 milli seconds
bHubContrCurrent 0 milli Ampere
DeviceRemovable 0x00
PortPwrCtrlMask 0xff
Hub Port Status:
Port 1: 0000.0503 highspeed power enable connect
Port 2: 0000.0100 power
Device Status: 0x0001
Self Powered

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Device Descriptor:
bLength 18
bDescriptorType 1
bcdUSB 2.00
bDeviceClass 9 Hub
bDeviceSubClass 0 Unused
bDeviceProtocol 1 Single TT
bMaxPacketSize0 64
idVendor 0x8087 Intel Corp.
idProduct 0x0024 Integrated Rate Matching Hub
bcdDevice 0.00
iManufacturer 0
iProduct 0
iSerial 0
bNumConfigurations 1
Configuration Descriptor:
bLength 9
bDescriptorType 2
wTotalLength 25
bNumInterfaces 1
bConfigurationValue 1
iConfiguration 0
bmAttributes 0xe0
Self Powered
Remote Wakeup
MaxPower 0mA
Interface Descriptor:
bLength 9
bDescriptorType 4
bInterfaceNumber 0
bAlternateSetting 0
bNumEndpoints 1
bInterfaceClass 9 Hub
bInterfaceSubClass 0 Unused
bInterfaceProtocol 0 Full speed (or root) hub
iInterface 0
Endpoint Descriptor:
bLength 7
bDescriptorType 5
bEndpointAddress 0x81 EP 1 IN
bmAttributes 3
Transfer Type Interrupt
Synch Type None
Usage Type Data
wMaxPacketSize 0x0001 1x 1 bytes
bInterval 12
Hub Descriptor:
bLength 9
bDescriptorType 41
nNbrPorts 4
wHubCharacteristic 0x0009
Per-port power switching
Per-port overcurrent protection
TT think time 8 FS bits
bPwrOn2PwrGood 50 * 2 milli seconds
bHubContrCurrent 0 milli Ampere
DeviceRemovable 0x00
PortPwrCtrlMask 0xff
Hub Port Status:
Port 1: 0000.0100 power
Port 2: 0000.0100 power
Port 3: 0000.0100 power
Port 4: 0000.0100 power
Device Qualifier (for other device speed):
bLength 10
bDescriptorType 6
bcdUSB 2.00
bDeviceClass 9 Hub
bDeviceSubClass 0 Unused
bDeviceProtocol 0 Full speed (or root) hub
bMaxPacketSize0 64
bNumConfigurations 1
Device Status: 0x0001
Self Powered

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Device Descriptor:
bLength 18
bDescriptorType 1
bcdUSB 2.00
bDeviceClass 9 Hub
bDeviceSubClass 0 Unused
bDeviceProtocol 1 Single TT
bMaxPacketSize0 64
idVendor 0x8087 Intel Corp.
idProduct 0x0024 Integrated Rate Matching Hub
bcdDevice 0.00
iManufacturer 0
iProduct 0
iSerial 0
bNumConfigurations 1
Configuration Descriptor:
bLength 9
bDescriptorType 2
wTotalLength 25
bNumInterfaces 1
bConfigurationValue 1
iConfiguration 0
bmAttributes 0xe0
Self Powered
Remote Wakeup
MaxPower 0mA
Interface Descriptor:
bLength 9
bDescriptorType 4
bInterfaceNumber 0
bAlternateSetting 0
bNumEndpoints 1
bInterfaceClass 9 Hub
bInterfaceSubClass 0 Unused
bInterfaceProtocol 0 Full speed (or root) hub
iInterface 0
Endpoint Descriptor:
bLength 7
bDescriptorType 5
bEndpointAddress 0x81 EP 1 IN
bmAttributes 3
Transfer Type Interrupt
Synch Type None
Usage Type Data
wMaxPacketSize 0x0001 1x 1 bytes
bInterval 12
Hub Descriptor:
bLength 9
bDescriptorType 41
nNbrPorts 6
wHubCharacteristic 0x0009
Per-port power switching
Per-port overcurrent protection
TT think time 8 FS bits
bPwrOn2PwrGood 50 * 2 milli seconds
bHubContrCurrent 0 milli Ampere
DeviceRemovable 0x00
PortPwrCtrlMask 0xff
Hub Port Status:
Port 1: 0000.0101 power connect
Port 2: 0000.0100 power
Port 3: 0000.0303 lowspeed power enable connect
Port 4: 0000.0303 lowspeed power enable connect
Port 5: 0000.0100 power
Port 6: 0000.0100 power
Device Qualifier (for other device speed):
bLength 10
bDescriptorType 6
bcdUSB 2.00
bDeviceClass 9 Hub
bDeviceSubClass 0 Unused
bDeviceProtocol 0 Full speed (or root) hub
bMaxPacketSize0 64
bNumConfigurations 1
Device Status: 0x0001
Self Powered

Bus 002 Device 003: ID 192f:0416 Avago Technologies, Pte.
Device Descriptor:
bLength 18
bDescriptorType 1
bcdUSB 2.00
bDeviceClass 0 (Defined at Interface level)
bDeviceSubClass 0
bDeviceProtocol 0
bMaxPacketSize0 8
idVendor 0x192f Avago Technologies, Pte.
idProduct 0x0416
bcdDevice 2.00
iManufacturer 0
iProduct 2 USB Optical Mouse
iSerial 0
bNumConfigurations 1
Configuration Descriptor:
bLength 9
bDescriptorType 2
wTotalLength 34
bNumInterfaces 1
bConfigurationValue 1
iConfiguration 0
bmAttributes 0xa0
(Bus Powered)
Remote Wakeup
MaxPower 98mA
Interface Descriptor:
bLength 9
bDescriptorType 4
bInterfaceNumber 0
bAlternateSetting 0
bNumEndpoints 1
bInterfaceClass 3 Human Interface Device
bInterfaceSubClass 1 Boot Interface Subclass
bInterfaceProtocol 2 Mouse
iInterface 0
HID Device Descriptor:
bLength 9
bDescriptorType 33
bcdHID 1.11
bCountryCode 0 Not supported
bNumDescriptors 1
bDescriptorType 34 Report
wDescriptorLength 71
Report Descriptors:
** UNAVAILABLE **
Endpoint Descriptor:
bLength 7
bDescriptorType 5
bEndpointAddress 0x81 EP 1 IN
bmAttributes 3
Transfer Type Interrupt
Synch Type None
Usage Type Data
wMaxPacketSize 0x0006 1x 6 bytes
bInterval 10
Device Status: 0x0000
(Bus Powered)

Bus 002 Device 004: ID 04d9:1702 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc.
Device Descriptor:
bLength 18
bDescriptorType 1
bcdUSB 1.10
bDeviceClass 0 (Defined at Interface level)
bDeviceSubClass 0
bDeviceProtocol 0
bMaxPacketSize0 8
idVendor 0x04d9 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc.
idProduct 0x1702
bcdDevice 4.02
iManufacturer 1
iProduct 2 USB Keyboard
iSerial 0
bNumConfigurations 1
Configuration Descriptor:
bLength 9
bDescriptorType 2
wTotalLength 59
bNumInterfaces 2
bConfigurationValue 1
iConfiguration 0
bmAttributes 0xa0
(Bus Powered)
Remote Wakeup
MaxPower 100mA
Interface Descriptor:
bLength 9
bDescriptorType 4
bInterfaceNumber 0
bAlternateSetting 0
bNumEndpoints 1
bInterfaceClass 3 Human Interface Device
bInterfaceSubClass 1 Boot Interface Subclass
bInterfaceProtocol 1 Keyboard
iInterface 0
HID Device Descriptor:
bLength 9
bDescriptorType 33
bcdHID 1.10
bCountryCode 0 Not supported
bNumDescriptors 1
bDescriptorType 34 Report
wDescriptorLength 62
Report Descriptors:
** UNAVAILABLE **
Endpoint Descriptor:
bLength 7
bDescriptorType 5
bEndpointAddress 0x81 EP 1 IN
bmAttributes 3
Transfer Type Interrupt
Synch Type None
Usage Type Data
wMaxPacketSize 0x0008 1x 8 bytes
bInterval 10
Interface Descriptor:
bLength 9
bDescriptorType 4
bInterfaceNumber 1
bAlternateSetting 0
bNumEndpoints 1
bInterfaceClass 3 Human Interface Device
bInterfaceSubClass 0 No Subclass
bInterfaceProtocol 0 None
iInterface 0
HID Device Descriptor:
bLength 9
bDescriptorType 33
bcdHID 1.10
bCountryCode 0 Not supported
bNumDescriptors 1
bDescriptorType 34 Report
wDescriptorLength 101
Report Descriptors:
** UNAVAILABLE **
Endpoint Descriptor:
bLength 7
bDescriptorType 5
bEndpointAddress 0x82 EP 2 IN
bmAttributes 3
Transfer Type Interrupt
Synch Type None
Usage Type Data
wMaxPacketSize 0x0008 1x 8 bytes
bInterval 10
Device Status: 0x0000
(Bus Powered)
```

I use ubuntu 14.04

UPDATE :
still does not work. I wrote to the list of users alsa, this was his response.

**That's not an ALSA problem, but most probably a firmware bug. A device
with bNumConfigurations == 0 is invalid. Copied the linux-usb list.**
**Could you follow the instructions in this document and generate a usbmon
trace when connecting the device? I'd like to know whether the entire
device descriptor is garbled.**

[https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/usb/usbmon.txt]

Thanks,
Daniel Mack

Comment: Did you try another USB port? It may be a cable/connector issue.

Comment: Have you tried both USB and connecting it through "MIDI in" on your soundcard (if you have that option)? See http://linuxmusicians.com/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=10269

Comment: rodrigo I tried using another usb port, and nothing.

Comment: Kokkie, my soundcard not have that option

Comment: **I have a Samson Carbon 61 and had exactly the same problem... after almost giving up and returning the keyboard I had an idea: look for pointer devices and deactivate the one S Carbon is using. It works after you out the following commands in the terminal and you switch off and on the keyboard:

Determine the device id (the device name should be something with touchpad or glidepoint)
xinput list

{Mine comes at "15" as "James Lam SAMSON Carbon61"

Disable it (e.g. here the device id is 15)
xinput set-prop 15 "Device Enabled" 0`code`**


I fail to determine the id

Comment: What is your output from "xinput list"?

Comment: `⎡ Virtual core pointer id=2 [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer id=4 [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ USB Optical Mouse id=8 [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard id=3 [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard id=5 [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button id=6 [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button id=7 [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Eee PC WMI hotkeys id=11 [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳   USB Keyboard id=9 [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳   USB Keyboard id=10 [slave  keyboard (3)]`

Answer (score 1):

**Here is the solution**

1. Go to the official website of Samson
2. Download the firmware version 1.25 for the midi controller and application to upgrade the firmware
3. Update the firmware on windows
4. Enjoying in Linux

Now lsusb says

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 17a0:344b Samson Technologies Corp.
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 192f:0416 Avago Technologies, Pte. ADNS-5700 Optical Mouse Controller (3-button)
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 04d9:1702 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. Keyboard LKS02
```

And lsusb -v

```
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 17a0:344b Samson Technologies Corp.
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
bLength 18
bDescriptorType 1
bcdUSB 2.00
bDeviceClass 0 (Defined at Interface level)
bDeviceSubClass 0
bDeviceProtocol 0
bMaxPacketSize0 64
idVendor 0x17a0 Samson Technologies Corp.
idProduct 0x344b
bcdDevice 2.00
iManufacturer 1
iProduct 2
iSerial 3
bNumConfigurations 1
```

Much better :)

amidi -l in ubuntu 14.04

```
Dir Device Name
IO hw:1,0,0 Samson Carbon61 MIDI 1
```

dmesg in ubuntu 14.04

```
usb 4-2: new full-speed USB device number 2 using ohci-pci
usb 4-2: New USB device found, idVendor=17a0, idProduct=344b
usb 4-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
usb 4-2: Product: Samson Carbon61 
usb 4-2: Manufacturer: Samson Technologies
usb 4-2: SerialNumber: 8D7751814956
usbcore: registered new interface driver snd-usb-audio
```

Thanks to **Daniel Mack**

Answer (score 0):

from your dmesg and "xinput list" output I see it's id=9;
↳ USB Keyboard id=9 [slave keyboard (3)]

Have your tried the answer from gallecito?

Disable it (e.g. here the device id is 9)

```
xinput set-prop 9 "Device Enabled" 0
```

After that switch the keyboard off and back on.

Comment: Still not working.  I'll try contact with alsa user list, hopefully it is something simple like to register the USB product identifier in some database that associates the usb-midi driver. Thanks for your time!

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck and sorry I couldn't help out.

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the problem. It was USB related, the X server is something completely different.